# Replace special character of number to words BI publisher

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I am trying to replace the "-" in  FIVE HUNDRED THIRTY-FIVE AND NINETY-EIGHT to blank. However, whenever I have tried to add the xdoxslt in xdofx, it seems to display a blank value

```
<?xdofx:replace(xdoxslt:toCheckNumber($_XDOLOCALE, 535.98,'USD','CASE_UPPER','DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS') ,'-', ' ')?>
```

This will display FIVE HUNDRED THIRTY-FIVE AND NINETY-EIGHT

```
<?xdoxslt:toCheckNumber($_XDOLOCALE, Order_Total_ID10,'USD' ,'CASE_UPPER','DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS')?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<?xdoxslt:replace(xdoxslt:toCheckNumber($_XDOLOCALE, 535.98,'USD','CASE_UPPER','DECIMAL_STYLE_WORDS') ,'-', ' ')?>
```